# Compile .ts and .less with Webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, less

I am trying to compile TypeScript and Less files using separate entries.

package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "typescript": "^3.3.3",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.29.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  }
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        ts: './TypeScript/index.ts',
        less: './Less/index.less'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.less', '.css'],
        alias: { // workaround issue with lib https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize/issues/814
            'cldr$': 'cldrjs',
            'cldr': 'cldrjs/dist/cldr'
        }
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle-[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/bundles/')
    },
    devtool: isProduction ? 'none' : 'source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'ts-loader'
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(le|c)ss$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                }, {
                    loader: 'css-loader'
                }, {
                    loader: 'less-loader'
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
            // both options are optional
            filename: '[name].css',
            chunkFilename: '[id].css',

        })
    ],
};
```

It generates 3 files: bundle-less.js, bundle-ts.js and less.css. How do I prevent from generating bundle-less.js? Because I only need compiled typescript and .css files. Or is there a reason it should be included in my website? I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue of `mini-css-extract-plugin`. You can check the progress of it and some workarounds [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/151).

There is no need to include `bundle-less.js` in your final html. Also you can confirm yourself that it contains only some boilerplate webpack code, since the style has been extracted from it.

#### Possible workarounds

- Exclude this file from `HtmlWebpackPlugin` *(if you are using it to generate your final html)*

```js
plugins: [
    //...
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'template.html',
            excludeAssets: [/bundle\-less\.js/],
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackExcludeAssetsPlugin()
],
```

- Delete this file after build

  - Simply `rm` on the `postbuild` npm hook
  - Configure [del-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del-webpack-plugin)*(or similar)* to delete these unwanted files